# MTL materials are not being applied

Tags: materials, import

I have some free downloaded OBJ 3D objects like this cat (http://www.cadnav.com/plus/download.php?open=0&aid=48009&cid=3). It have its material MTL file to give the cat a real appearance. (http://img.cadnav.com/allimg/190709/cadnav-1ZF9121629.jpeg)
I have both files in same folder, of course. However, after I import the OBJ and press Alt + Z, it seems Blender ignores the texture. It happens with other OBJ/MLT imported.

Please, could you help me? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the .mtl file is not assigning the texture. There is no `map_Kd` attribute saved.

```
newmtl Material__27
illum 4
Kd 0.50 0.50 0.50
Ka 0.00 0.00 0.00
Tf 1.00 1.00 1.00
Ni 1.00
Ks 0.50 0.50 0.50
Ns 18.00
```

If you append `map_Kd cat.png` as a new line, it will load the mesh with a texture. However the UV layout seems to be made with a mirror modifier applied which causes the texture to look very glitchy. This could be solved if you're willing to fix it.

Comment: I did what you suggested and it worked like a charm. I can't understand why Cadnav web doesn't test previously 3D models before put them to download. It's a pity.